# Github OAuth2 access token endpoint returning 'not found'. [Node]

Tags: node.js, github, oauth-2.0

Currently trying to get a user's access token back from github, but receiving the following object:

```
{"error": "Not Found"}
```

I can't see exactly what I'm doing wrong with this fetch request and I believe I have all the right tokens etc. The guide I'm following uses (I think it's called) superagent, while I'm just using regular ol' isomorphic-fetch so perhaps that's where some of the confusion lies.

Here's my code:

```
 fetch("https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token", {
    method: "POST",
    body: {
      client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: "/"
    },
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(body => {
      console.log("body" + JSON.stringify(body));
      res.send({
        success: true,
        message: "Succesfully Logged In!",
        userToken: body.access_token
      });
    });
```

I double checked the env.client_id, and the env.client_secret and they're both being imported correctly. The code I can only guess at, but it seems to be right from when I logged it out.

Answer (score 1):

For reasons I don't yet know, my

```
process.env.CLIENT_ID
```

Was somehow being imported with quotation marks at the end of it, thus invalidating it. This is not the case for the other variables, and so I am a little puzzled. However, removing the quotation marks entirely and having the id stand on its own was my solution.

EDIT: That was only part of the problem. Currently I've only had success using superagent over fetch for some reason.